# What PyCharm's Invalidate Caches/Restart feature actually does

Tags: python, caching, pycharm, purge

Some time ago I updated my PyCharm to new major version and since then I started to notice that my completion suggestions contain 2 copies of all options, check this screenshot:

[image]

I tried to invalidate/restart from main menu without any luck to clear this. So I just went to `~/Library/Caches/PyCharm` and kill with fire all content inside remote_sources.
After that I get couple of fatal IDE errors in PyCharm but after indexing and couple of restarts it works fine and I see no more duplicates.

So in my particular case `Invalidate Caches/Restart` was absolutely useless. Here goes my question: what exactly this feature clears and when it is helpful?

Comment: sounds like a question to send to the JetBrains support.  they are pretty responsive.

Comment: So invalidate/restart should do exactly what I've done manually?

Comment: do you usually know _exactly_ what a piece of software you didn't write is supposed to do?  I don't...

Comment: Issue for the the JetBrains support

Comment: If you have raised an issue with JetBrains, I guess it would be better to put a link here. For those who come searching answer for this question.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember if I did :) I abandon macos in favor of Linux a long time ago, and haven't encountered this issue since then.